# How to fill a polygon generated by importing a .dxf file to Altium?

Tags: altium, dxf, import

I am trying to import a .dxf file to Altium. I was able to import the file, but I could not fill it up with copper trace completely. I tried to draw a polygon to cover it and use 'Explode polygon to primitives' option to fill it with copper trace. I tried to change the clearance rules to make sure that the entire area gets filled up.

Is there an easier way to import a .dxf file to Alitum while making sure that it is filled up with copper trace during the import without having to go through all these hassles?

Comment: Can you use regions instead?

Comment: Have you tried importing a solid in to Altium?

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't a way to import DXF with default copper fills, if the fills were not already there originally. This is out of the scope of a DXF import. You will need to select the contours of the area you want to fill and make a copy on another layer for back-up, then select the contour and "create a polygon from selected primitives" with the tools->convert commands etc. then you can fill in as you wish... You may need to then move your fills to the required layers.